# Android Twitter Application Development and Usage of TextView and Linkify

Tags: android, twitter

I'm on developing a twitter kind of Application where in I want that the user would be displayed the timelines and the Textview in the Lists require to perform clicks on (http://)URLs, (@)usernames, and (#)hasTags and I want to invoke custom methods over these actions, I have used the Linkify class and the actions but where of no use because the customization that i require cannot be incorporated.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want done?

Comment: "This is a #test of regular expressions with http://example.com links as used in @twitter. http://twitter.com."  if this an text in the TextView then I require #test, http://example.com, @twitter and http://twitter.com as separate strings and Clickable from Textview and if Clicked I require them to be handled in a custom method for giving my actions over these String

Comment: Is this action possible in any ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution to the problem to check it out go to the below mentioned link http://www.orangeapple.org/?p=354

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.
The main idea is to split the text words and creating a TextView for each one, wrapping each line with horizontal LinearLayout and the lines into vertical LinearLayout:

```
private LinearLayout mDescription; // vertical LinearLayout 

    private void setDescriptionText(String twitterText){
    String[] splitted;

    String regexp = "(@[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(#[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(http://[-a-zA-Z0-9/._]*)|(https://[-a-zA-Z0-9/._]*)|( )";

    TextSplitter splitter = new TextSplitter(regexp);
    splitted = splitter.split(twitterText);

    TextView[] textViews = new TextView[splitted.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        final String str = splitted[i];
        TextView textView = new TextView(mDescription.getContext());  
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
        textViews[i] = textView;


        textView.setText(str);
        textView.setTypeface(roboReg);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        if (str.startsWith("@")){
            textView.setTextColor(mLinkColor);
            textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startWebViewActivity("https://twitter.com/"+str.substring(1));
                }
            });
        }else if (str.startsWith("#")){
            textView.setTextColor(mLinkColor);
            textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startWebViewActivity("https://twitter.com/#!/search/?q="+str.substring(1) + "&src=hash");
                }
            });

        }else if (str.startsWith("http://") || str.startsWith("https://")){
            textView.setTextColor(mLinkColor);
            textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startWebViewActivity(str);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    int maxWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 210, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    populateText(mDescription, maxWidth , textViews, mDescription.getContext());

}

private void populateText(LinearLayout ll,int maxWidth, View[] views, Context mContext) {

    ll.removeAllViews();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    int widthSoFar = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        views[i].measure(0, 0);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(views[i].getMeasuredWidth(),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LL.addView(views[i], params);
        LL.measure(0, 0);
        widthSoFar += views[i].getMeasuredWidth();// YOU MAY NEED TO ADD THE MARGINS
        if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth) {
            ll.addView(newLL);

            newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LL
                    .getMeasuredWidth(), LL.getMeasuredHeight());
            newLL.addView(LL, params);
            widthSoFar = LL.getMeasuredWidth();
        } else {
            newLL.addView(LL);
        }
    }
    ll.addView(newLL);
}

private class TextSplitter {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private boolean keep_delimiters;

    public TextSplitter(Pattern pattern, boolean keep_delimiters) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.keep_delimiters = keep_delimiters;
    }

    public TextSplitter(String pattern, boolean keep_delimiters) {
        this(Pattern.compile(pattern == null ? "" : pattern), keep_delimiters);
    }


    public TextSplitter(String pattern) {
        this(pattern, true);
    }

    public String[] split(String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            text = "";
        }

        int last_match = 0;
        LinkedList<String> splitted = new LinkedList<String>();

        Matcher m = this.pattern.matcher(text);

        while (m.find()) {

            splitted.add(text.substring(last_match, m.start()));

            if (this.keep_delimiters) {
                splitted.add(m.group());
            }

            last_match = m.end();
        }

        splitted.add(text.substring(last_match));

        return splitted.toArray(new String[splitted.size()]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many `addLinks()` methods on [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html), one of which may let you accomplish your aims, if your goal is to start an activity from those links.

You can also examine the source code to [`Linkify`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java&q=package:android%20Linkify&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) to see how you might create your own that meets your needs.

Comment: But I require to get a method call, or an interface method for the Particular Regex Match how is that possible using the Linkify

Comment: Now, thats what my exact requirement is. Can that be achieved using some other ways. Please any pointer in that direction would really help me a lot

Comment: You would have to try to figure out how `TextView` handles link clicks.